# Why does USER_UNUSED_COL_TABS contain only amount of unused columns but not names?

Tags: sql, oracle

The following dictionary view:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_UNUSED_COL_TABS
```

gives only the table names along with unused columns count. Why there is unable to see column names which has been marked as UNUSED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you couldn't do anything with that information if you had it. You can't reinstate them, or drop them explicitly. You can also add a new column with the same name, so if you then marked that as unused, it would have to have a way to let you distinguish between them.

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53388):

> You can view all tables with columns marked `UNUSED` in the data
>   dictionary views `USER_UNUSED_COL_TABS`, `DBA_UNUSED_COL_TABS`, and
>   `ALL_UNUSED_COL_TABS`.
>
> ... After a column has been marked `UNUSED`, you have no access to
>   that column. A `SELECT *` query will not retrieve data from unused
>   columns. In addition, the names and types of columns marked `UNUSED`
>   will not be displayed during a `DESCRIBE`, and you can add to the
>   table a new column with the same name as an unused column.

All you can really do with unused columns is drop them, with the `DROP UNUSED COLUMNS` clause or by dropping another column. [This view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_2127.htm) shows which tables it might be worth running `DROP UNUSED COLUMNS` against, I suppose, but isn't really of much use otherwise as far as I can tell.

Comment: I wouldn't say it has no use. It would help me diagnose an invalid ID error if I could prove the name of the column. Dropping the unused columns isn't always so convenient on compressed tables, so it'd be quite helpful to know beforehand that it would fix the error.

Comment: How does an unused column give you an invalid ID error? Do you mean a query that used to work now errors, and you want to be able to show that it's because a column has been marked unused?

Comment: It happened to me with a non-proprietary software that wasn't updating its views when the underlying table had a column moved to unused. Or at least I think that was the issue. I never got to the bottom of it because I didn't know which unused column was there. I thought views auto-updated, so I'm not sure if this was something else going on.